# Vault to Git to Mercurial not preserving dates

Tags: git, mercurial, sourcegear-vault, mercurial-convert

Using https://github.com/AndreyNikiforov/vault2git I was able to convert a Vault repo to Git and then used Mercurial's `hg convert` to get a hg repo. The only issues is that after running `hg convert` the dates on the change set commit dates are incorrect.

The dates show the time the change set was converted from got to mercurial  instead of the commit date.

Is there something else I need to do to preserve the dates?

Comment: Probably redundant question, but why would you further convert from git to mercurial? :)

Comment: My goal is to get the repo into mercurial and the vault2git was the only vault to x I found.

Comment: @Omar Are the timestamps in the git repo correct?

Comment: Yes, the Git timestamps are correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got this working by removing the code that checks the committer information in the `hg convert` `git` extension in the file https://www.mercurial-scm.org/repo/hg-stable/file/09b200396384/hgext/convert/git.py lines `125` to `130`:

```
        if n == "committer":
            p = v.split()
            tm, tz = p[-2:]
            committer = " ".join(p[:-2])
            if committer[0] == "<": committer = committer[1:-1]
            committer = self.recode(committer)
```

Once you remove this, `hg convert` will use the author information for the date. You'll need to copy over the convert extension from the repo link, modify it and then add it to TortoiseHg.

**Why this needs to be done:**

When committing with `git`, there are two records in the changeset metadata: `committer` and `author`.

- Author is the person responsible for the code.
- Committer is the person who actually committed the changes to the repository.

This distinction is important in an open-source project where the person who authored the code isn't necessarily the person that commits it to the repository: usually there are maintainers (committers) of the project that accept pull requests from a contributor (author) and commit it to the repository.

`Vault2Git` uses the Vault checkin info (committer and date of commit) as the git changeset author info. The git committer info uses the git user's info and the actual date of commit (your default user for the repository). You can see this difference by doing `git cat-file <rev hash>` on a changeset that `Vault2Git` does.

This works fine for git, but when you run `hg convert`, Mercurial uses the `author` name and the `committer` date to create the Mercruial changeset metadata.

Answer (score 1):

You could try [hg-git](http://hg-git.github.com/) rather than the convert extension. It's a bi-directional bridge between the two that is meant to be lossless. That must include dates otherwise the hashes would change each time you pulled.

Comment: Tried doing that but for some reason it wouldn't clone the git repo that was created with vault2git.

Comment: Makes me wonder if there's something a little odd with the git repo that vault2git created. It's managed to cause two methods (which normally work) to fail.